# kerberos error while creating database

Tags: centos-7, kerberos, hadoop

kerberos error while creating database

````
Loading random data
Initializing database '/var/lib/krb5kadc/principal' for realm 'HADOOP.COM',
master key name 'K/M@HADOOP.COM'
You will be prompted for the database Master Password.
It is important that you NOT FORGET this password.
Enter KDC database master key:
Re-enter KDC database master key to verify:
kdb5_util: No such file or directory while creating database '/var/lib/krb5kadc/                                                                                    principal'```
````

Comment: This is not google. If you do have an actual question please write it down. What did you try to do? What didn't work? What is your goal? What did you try to fix it? Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the database directory doesn't exist. It looks like your kdc.conf has a typo:

- Your KDC configuration tells it to put the database under `/var/lib/krb5kadc/`.
- The standard directory name for MIT Kerberos is usually `/var/lib/krb5kdc/`.